# how to concatenate two tuples and retain their shapes?

Tags: python

I have two lists,

```
train = [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
test = [0, 1, 2]
```

What can i do with NumPy or for loops to make the final result look like this:

```
final = [([1, 2], [0]), ([0, 2], [1]), ([0, 1], [2])]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function to do it:

```
final = list(zip(train, [[t] for t in test]))
```

The zip function pairs up corresponding items in iterable containers, and returns a zip item, which can be converted to a list to give you the desired result.

For further reading: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for you to do that type of output as numpy, because numpy is formal to use with tensors/arrays. Therefore, if your input like this, you have to convert them to tensors and the result will be a tensor combining by 2 tensors:

```
train = np.asarray(train) #3x2 shape
test = np.asarray(test).reshape(-1,1) # reshape to the same shape with 3x1 shape
np.append(train,test,axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]]) #output
```

Else, it would be better if you use zip and list to iterate through both list train and list test to get your result:

```
list(zip(train, [list(t) for t in test]))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input - yes it makes sense I should turn them into arrays/tensors first. thank you. However, your ouput differs from mine. I'm not trying to put them together in the same array, but in separate arrays within the same section. i.e. not [[1,2,0]] but [[1,2],[0]]. That is my problem. Whenever i tried to the zip method, it works but it's not efficient for longer lists.

Comment: [[1,2],[0]] cant be a tensor, how can you have the shape sth like this. For your result, it is a list of 2 arrays. No way Numpy can do this. The only way is zip and list

Comment: For  [[1,2,0]] If you want to select the test, you just need to slice arrays by index [:,-1]